# Is it possible to trigger a node scale-up with Pod Affinity/Antiaffinity rules?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod, autoscaling

I have a nodepool in **AKS** with autoscaling enabled. Here is a simple scenario I am trying to achieve.

I have 1 node running a single pod (`A`) with label `deployment=x`. I have another pod (`B`) with a podAntiAffinity rule to avoid nodes running pods with `deployment=x` label.

```
affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
              - key: deployment
                operator: In
                values:
                - x
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

The behavior I am seeing is that Pod `B` gets scheduled to the same node as Pod `A`. I would have wanted Pod `B` to be in `Pending` state until the autoscaler added a new node that satisfies the podAntiAffinity rule and schedule Pod `B` to the new node. Is this possible to do?

```
Kubernetes Version: 1.22.6
```

-- EDIT--

This example does trigger a node scale up, so it's doing what I expect it to do and that working for me.

Comment: Can you please share the podAntiAffinity rule you are using for pod B.

Comment: @rock'nrolla I have shared the podAntiAffinity rule in the post.

Comment: Totally my bad. I re-read & realized your question was for `podAntiAffinity` rule in a `pod definition` and not in a `deployment`. I have deleted my answer now - thus commenting here.
The behavior which you are seeing is odd as your `podAntiAffinity` rule for a `pod definition` seems right. Moreover, I tried the same rule in a minikube 1 node cluster and the pod B goes into `Pending` with `Reason: FailedScheduling` & the `Message: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match pod anti-affinity rules. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod`

Comment: Maybe share the output of `kubectl describe <pod A> | grep Labels` - just to make the label on that one is correct.

Comment: @rock'nrolla you are right, that's my bad. I was having issues at first but came up with this simple scenario it does do what I expect it to do which helped me find my solution. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @rock'nrolla So does this not work with a `Deployment` object?

Answer (score 0):

The `podAntiAffinity` example I posted works as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You should change key for search. As I understand, once you select key: deployment, you are looking in deployments, it's not related to the node. Try this example:

```
podAntiAffinity:
  requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    - labelSelector:
        matchExpressions:
          - key: app.kubernetes.io/instance
            operator: In
            values:
              - name-of-deployment
      topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

Comment: It is looking for the label with key `deployment` and not the deployment object.